# fppf/ etale Cohomology calculate with Cech cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology, grothendieck-topologies, descent

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with one (so living in standard commutative algebra setting) and
let $\phi: R \to S$ a *faithfully flat*. Then the so called [Amitsur complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amitsur_complex)
$R \to S^{\otimes \bullet +1}$ is exact and determines
a faithfully flat resolution of $R$.

Applying the multiplicative group scheme functor
$\mathbb{G}_m$ to this complex and taking cohomology
gives exactly the fppf Cech cohomology
$H^i_{Cech, fppf}(S^{\otimes \bullet +1}, \mathbb{G}_m)$ with respect the
fppf cover $Spec(S) \to Spec(R)$.

We want to compare the fppf Cech cohomology with fppf cohomology of
$H^i_{fppf}(R, \mathbb{G}_m)$. In general there exist only a morphism

$$  H^i_{Cech, fppf}(S^{\otimes \bullet +1}, \mathbb{G}_m)
     \to H^i_{fppf}(R, \mathbb{G}_m)    $$

since often Cech cannot resolve 'fine' enough. For which class of rings $R$ there exist a fppf resolution $R \to S \to ...$ of $R$ which induces an isomorphism between associated Cech and fppf cohomology? What about the same problem with etale cohomology instead of fppf? Where (if that's true) a complete proof can be found? For which rings do moreover the
fppf cohomology $H^i_{fppf}(R, \mathbb{G}_m)$ and etale cohomology
$H^i_{etale}(R, \mathbb{G}_m)$ coinside?

Comment: Normally I do not downvote, but here I gave a -1. The reason is not because your question is uninteresting. But you expect an answer (which will take a lot of time from people) and use expressions like "comm ring", " commalg setting", "fppf coho", "etale coho". Yes, one can understand it, but you do not take the time to write proper sentences.

Comment: Hi Paul, well if the downvote is only based on used abbreviations, then 
ok, I wrote them out. But I think that it would be to much additionally
to explain the used terminology like what is fppf, etale, Cech 
cohomology etc, do you agree with me? That can be looked up somewhere in internet or appropriated literature

Comment: Yes, of course. But I regard that as specialist jargon, and it is clear to me that you cannot explain everything in detail. My point was this: Reading your question made the impression that you wanted to save a few seconds of your time, but you expected that other people spend much more time to answer it. And I think this is somewhat disrespectful, although I am sure this was not your intention. I retracted my downvote and gave an upvote instead.

Comment: You want a condition on $R$ not on $S$ ? I mean, if you take $S=R$ then the Cech cohomology is trivial whereas its fppf cohomology may not be.

Comment: @Roland : yes  of course. I should it maybe make more precise

Comment: @katalaveino I don't understand your edit, for every ring there is a faithfully flat algebra for which Cech cohomology is trivial. I don't believe you are asking which ring have trivial fppf cohomology.

Comment: @Roland: sorry, you right of course. What I wanted to know if for every commutative ring $R$
there *exist* a faithfully flat $R \to S$ such that the associated Amitsur
complex, which determines the Cech cohomology, determines *also* the 
fppf cohomology, that is the comparison map above is iso. Thank you for pointing it out, otherwise my formulation
is of course nonsense.